# Append data to a saved variable using matfile()

Tags: matlab, append, mat-file

I have some random 2D data `fuffa` that I save to a file `fuffalo`:

```
fuffa=rand(10,10);
save('fuffalo','fuffa', '-v7.3')
```

I then go through a loop that generates other `fuffa` data that I want to append (in the third dimension) to the saved variable. To do this, I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082884/how-to-append-in-mat-file-row-or-columnwise-cellmatrix) suggestion:

```
m1 = matfile('fuffalo.mat', 'Writable', true);

for ii=1:3
   fuffa2=rand(10,10);    
   m1.fuffa(1:10,1:10,end+1)=fuffa2;
end
```

However, at `ii=2` I get the following error:

> Variable 'fuffa' has 2 dimensions in the file, this does not match the 3 dimensions in the indexing subscripts.

How can I convince MATLAB to append in the third dimension?

Comment: Can you append in the first dimension? `fuffa = rand(1,10,10)`

Comment: yeah, I guess. do you know why in this way it works?

Comment: Because matlab automatically removes trailing singleton dimensions after the first two.

Comment: not (only) at `ii=2`, you should be getting the error for `ii=1` as well

Comment: The first two dimensions. Not entries. So a [20 x 1] vector stays a [20 x 1] vector. But a [20 x 20 x 1] matrix becomes a [20 x 20] matrix. The third, singleton, dimension is removed. It's one of the quirks of matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are accessing the file on disk, not a workspace variable, you may be encountering issues with expanding the number of dimensions. You would not have this issue dealing with variables which are stored in-memory (like if you used `load` instead of `matfile`).

To avoid this, the best approach would be [pre-allocation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). I'm going to assume though that this is a simplification of your actual problem, and you need to be able to do such 3D extensions to a potentially 2D array.

In this case, just use `cat` to concatenate in the 3rd dimension:

```
fuffa=rand(10,10);
save('fuffalo','fuffa', '-v7.3')
m1 = matfile('fuffalo.mat', 'Writable', true);
for ii=1:3
    fuffa2=rand(10,10);
    % Concatenating in the 3rd dimension, avoiding used 'end' which 
    % assumes that dimension already exists
    m1.fuffa=cat(3,m1.fuffa,fuffa2);
end
% m1.fuffa <10x10x4 double>
```

Note that by doing this, you are bringing the entirety of your .mat data into memory for the concatenation, defeating the point of `matfile()`. However, your previous method would face the same problem, since in the [docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) we see:

> Using the `end` keyword as part of an index causes MATLAB to load the entire variable into memory.

As stated before, you're probably better off with pre-allocation!

Comment: The file is an HDF5 container. The data in it has fixed dimensions, but you could just as well first store a 3D matrix `10x10x2` and overwrite the second fuffa. It then is specified in the container as 3D and you should be able to append to it.

Comment: The `matfile()` function allows the user to access data directly from the file on disk rather than in memory. "Workspace" was, again, probably the wrong choice of words by me. See the [docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) for more, but basically this is faster than using `load` for large data sets, because the data is never fully loaded into memory. So a `MAT-file` object is in the workspace, but this doesn't contain the data, just references it.